# Collapse all opened containers in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've seen similar questions to mine but none of them answers my question.

I have created a collapsible div component which expands itself on click. But I want it to work in a way that once one div is expanded it will collapse all other expanded components.

**Parent where I include collapsible component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Collapsible } from '../../components';

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Collapsible label="First label">
        <p>Children</p>
      </Collapsible>

      <Collapsible label="Second label">
        <p>Children</p>
      </Collapsible>

      <Collapsible label="Third label">
        <p>Children</p>
      </Collapsible>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

**Collapsible component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Collapsible extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      opened: false,
    };

    this.openCollapsible = this.openCollapsible.bind(this);

  }

  openCollapsible() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      opened: !prevState.opened,
    }));
  }

  render() {

  const { label, children } = this.props;
  const { opened } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 onClick={this.openCollapsible}>
        {label}
      </h2>
      {opened ? <div>{children}</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default Collapsible;
```

So everything works fine I just need a way to when one collapsible component is expanded collapse all others. Any help will mean a lot even if its just poiting to the right article where I can search for help.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/collapsible-component-tnhtn

Best wishes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to maintain id/index of open div in your parent div.

`state = {openedId: null}`

You can pass isOpen prop with every `Collapsible` component checking if it's id and `openedId` are same. Also onClick you'll have to update the openedId in the parent component.

```
handleClick = (id) => {
   this.setState({openedId: id})
}

....


 <Collapsible 
    label="First label" 
    id={1}
    isOpen={id === openedId} 
    handleClick={this.handleClick}
 >
        <p>Children</p>
  </Collapsible>
```

Here's the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/collapsible-component-131hd)

I would suggest you to render the `Collapsible` elements via a config, you can create an array of objects, something like this

```
const config = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: 'First Label',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'Second Label',
  },
];

....

config.map(({id, label} => <Collapsible label="Second label" id={2}>)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the clear answer and also sandbox! Works perfectly and I will use config for it.

Comment: This I think is the right answer. Check out this codepen as well if you want to keep your parent component functional, as it uses hooks:

https://codesandbox.io/s/collapsible-component-61j8e?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I think having a property in the state of your parent like

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
     
      openedDiv: someBool
    };

  }
```

will allow  you to keep track of what div is "opened", So you could pass that to the div that is supposed to be open, and pass your other value to the closed divs, Or you could use that property to keep track of the "actual div" that is open

So you basically need something to keep track of the current opened one!

Comment: Thanks! I will try to reproduce it now. 

If you have time to reproduce it I created sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/collapsible-component-tnhtn